# HTTP/2 Server Push with AWS S3 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting a static website on AWS. The files are hosted in an S3 bucket. My end users connects to CloudFront Edge, and CloudFront grabs the content from "bucket_name.s3-website-var.aws_region.amazonaws.com".

I am wondering how I could server-push the assets required by the HTML pages to my clients' browsers. Is it possible with Lambda Functions? How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure its not supported yet. At least the last time I did research on it.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dear-cloudfront-wheres-server-push-0-rtt-http3-almost-agarwalla/?articleId=6662735421019160577